# Positive look ahead regex confusing

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I'm building this regex with a positive look ahead in it. Basically it must select all text in the line up to last period that precedes a ":" and add a "|" to the end to delimit it. Some sample text below. I am testing this in gskinner and editpadpro which has full grep regex support apparently so if I could get the answers in that for I'd appreciate it.

The regex below works to a degree but I am unsure if it is correct. Also it falls down if the text contains brackets.

Finally I would like to add another ignore rule like the one that ignores but includes "Co." in the selection. This second ignore rule would ignore but include periods that have a single Capital letter before them. Sample text below too. Thanks for all the help.

```
^(?:[^|]+\|){3}(.*?)[^(?:Co)]\.(?=[^:]*?\:)

121| Ryan, T.N. |2001. |I like regex. But does it like me (2) 2: 615-631.
122| O' Toole, H.Y. |2004. |(Note on the regex). Pages 90-91 In: Ryan, A. & Toole, B.L. (Editors) Guide to the regex functionality in php. Timmy, Tommy& Stewie, Quohog. * Produced for Family Guy in Quohog.
```

Comment: Unless the regexp engine you are using is significantly different from Perl's, [^(?:Co)] matches any single character that isn't one of ":()?Co". That's surely not what you meant, was it?

Comment: thats there so that it will allow "Co." in the text without viewing the "Co." as the end of the match.

Comment: But what you've actually said is match anything ending with "." immediately preceded by a character which is none of "()?:Co". So it won't match "Fine, C." because the character that precedes the . is C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand what you want to do. But this part `[^(?:Co)]` is definitely not correct.

With the square brackets you are creating a character class, because of the `^` it is a negated class. That means at this place you don't want to match one of those characters `(?:Co)`, in other words it will match any other character than "?)(:Co".

**Update:**

I don't think its possible. How should I distinguish between L. Co. or something similar and the end of the sentence?

But I found another error in your regex. The last part `(?=[^:]*?\:)` should be `(?=[^.]*?\:)` if you want to match the last dot before the `:` with your expression it will match on the first dot.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uqin)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to select all text up to the last full stop(dot) that occurs before the ":" and then add a "|" character to the end in order to delimit it. The Co. part is there so that it skips over but still includes instances where Co. occurs as this is not to break the regex here. I also want to skip over items like "L." which could be names and so on.

Comment: thanks so much this is exactly what I wanted. The Co. or L. parts wont occur at the end of the string at all and wont occur after that last full stop, it works great thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This *seems* to do what you want.

```
(.*\.)(?=[^:]*?:)
```

It quite simply matches all text up to the last full stop that occurs before the colon.